# PagerTabStrip and PagerTitleStrip difference?

Tags: android, strip, pager

When should we use pagerTabStrip and when should we go for pagerTitleStrip???

What does the word interactive indicator and non-interactive indicator mean actually? Can you please explain me the difference and also can you please tell me if there is any difference in the UI?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`PagerTitleStrip` is just a strip which contain title texts; it just indicates the title of the section we're in.

`PagerTabStrip` is very similar to `PagerTitleStrip` but actually looks like a strip of tabs (it's used in the Play store tabs, and looks better in my opinion).

You can use `PagerTabStrip` if you are looking for a tab-like interface. If you are looking to customize PagerTitleStrip, you may want to see [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

Comment: `ViewPagerIndicator` (unlike `PagerTitleStrip` and `PagerTabStrip`) allows the user to scroll the page titles/tabs independent of the page shown in the `ViewPager`. Very handy.

Comment: ADT generates PagerTitleStrip (using "new Activity" wizard) instead PagerTabStrip. I reckon this is a source of confusion about this question...

Comment: Any idea how to make it using tabs style, but also that they won't be far from one another? I'm trying to solve it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27621425/878126 , to make it look like the pager of the Lollipop contacts app

Answer (score 5):

@Binoy Babu answer added every details about `PaterTitleStrip` and `PagerTabStrip`. I think to add image for example.

Reference link : http://blog.csdn.net/harvic880925/article/details/38521865

[image]
[image]

Above are `PagerTitleStrip` example, in which only title will scroll with page scrolling. **This do not indicate which page you are currently displaying**

[image]
[image]

Above is example of `PagerTabStrip` which is same to `PagerTitleStrip` **except** it indicates which page is displaying now. The current visible tab title is **underlined**

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Its a old post, but I want to point some differences between `PagerTabStrip` & `PagerTitleStrip`.

1. `PagerTabStrip` is interactive, means you can **click on the tabs to switch between screens**, which you cannot do that with `PagerTitleStrip`.
2. `PagerTabStrip` not only indicates the section name, but also has the **tab indicator (bottom border) that depicts the active tab**. On the contrary, `PagerTitleStrip` only indicates the section we're in through the title names, **but there is no tab indicator**.
3. Going through the docs, you will notice there are more public methods for `PagerTabStrip` compared to `PagerTitleStrip`. **Example:** `setTabIndicatorColor()` to set the tab indicator programmatically.
4. Also as mentioned by @BinoyBabu, plugin [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) allows to customize your pager strip in so many ways.